# How to code for a specific view contoller? - Apple Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to code a basic calculator for a specific view controller in my project, but I don't know the function to call my specific view controller.

I expect to be able to connect my outlets, but I can tell that it has to be in the scope of a specific function. I am unable to connect an outlet from any view controller other than the root.

I'm a student, and I've tried to look up function names for a specific ViewController, but I cannot find the right result.

[image: Label not attaching outlet]

[image: TextField only yielding an action]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to make different name just like:
ViewController
CalculatorViewController
and then you have to link this controller with its own screen like the image below:
[image]

and after that you will be able to link your outlets easily

Comment: I seem to be getting SIGABRT/NSUnknownKeyException every time I open my custom view controller. The problem appears to correlate to one of my outlets, and I made sure I haven't misnamed/renamed anything. Is there an extra step I'm missing?

Comment: can you show me the error? and it may be because you connected the same outlet to more than one label

Comment: I made a GitHub repository with the program and two screenshots - one of the error message and another of the connections menu of the outlet throwing the error. https://github.com/plates-the-one/unknown-key-exception

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna check it

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out. I needed to check 'Inherit Module From Target' under the ViewController class