# How do I use WKWebView on my second scene

Tags: swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have been trying to make a basic app for just a few days and I would like the Webkit View only to popup when a button is pressed. I have put the code I was using but it just showed the site and nothing else.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        self.view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!))
    }
}
```

Comment: you need it in the same view or in another view button pressed to pop up the WKWebView

Answer (score 0):

You can use it if you wanna make it in two separate views and show the 2nd viewController after clicking on the button:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
var webview: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webconfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webconfig)
        webview.uiDelegate = self
        view = webview
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myurl = URL(string: "https://google.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myurl!)
        webview.load(myRequest)
    }
```

[image]

but if you wanna it in the same view you can use the below by using button action:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
var webview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
    }
    
    func loadMyView() {
        let webconfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webconfig)
        webview.uiDelegate = self
        view = webview
    }
    func viewWeb()  {
        let myurl = URL(string: "https://google.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myurl!)
        webview.load(myRequest)
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonWebViewed(_ sender: Any) {
        loadMyView()
        viewWeb()
    }
    
   
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you but it does not seam to work is there some kind of setup I need for the first one ?

Comment: It's working fine with me, may you provide an image which you wanna implement

Comment: here https://imgur.com/a/rZF86LT https://imgur.com/a/pLoyp23

Comment: It's the same I did in my first solution, 1- you will make a button ,2- give it constrains (Top,bottom,training & leading), 3- connect it to the second ViewController by clicking on the button + Ctrl and drag it to the second controller,4- create an action for it in the same viewController,5- take the code written in my solution, That's it all

Comment: i probably sound so stupid but all i get is a black screen.

Comment: You have to set your initial virewController

Comment: I am so stupid where do i do that, sorry for using up your time Menaim

Comment: I think that I am getting this. I need to put it in the second scenes code thing right, but where do I find it?

Comment: First check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65115602/14437411 Then you will mark your viewController as in the link, go to the one beside number 2 in the link, finally check the box which says initial view

Comment: the simulator crashed with the code: Thread 1: signal SIGTERM

Comment: Connect each viewController with its class

Comment: you have to check both

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to upvote my answer and make it as the correct answer